# Teradata SQL: Failed [2616 : 22003] Numeric overflow occurred during computation

Tags: sql, overflow, teradata

I use Teradata to sum up a column of numbers to get the total, I get this error: "Failed [2616 : 22003] Numeric overflow occurred during computation.".

Even though I have already cast the number to decimal(38, 0). To verify if the total number actually exceeds 38 digits, I first sum up the column of numbers to several sub-categories, and use excel to sum up the sub-categories to get the total, while to my surprise, the total number is only 10 digits, definitely not exceeding 38 digits.

I'm quite wondered why this error occurs, or is there some misunderstanding on my side? Looking forward to some help on this. Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you show your actual calculation? Did you cast *before* or *after* summing?

Comment: You have to cautious when doing the CAST in this matter. You have to CAST the value that is summed up (put the CAST within the SUM), not the result (CAST around the SUM). ;)

Comment: I used "cast(sum(retail_price) as decimal(38,0)) as sales", the column of numbers is the variable "retail_price". Do you mean I should use "sum(cast(retail_price as decimal(38,0)))" instead?